# How to find the type of my distribution?

Tags: distributions, spss, nonparametric, simulation

I checked the normality of my data on SPSS and one of the variables is not normally distributed. I have the mean, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis , min and max values of my distribution. But I do not know the name of my distribution. How can I learn which type of distribution (Bernoulli, Beta, Binomial, Categorical, Exponential, Fixed, Gamma, Lognormal, Negative Binomial (Failures, Trials), Poisson, Range, Triangular, Uniform, Weibull) I have? If I can find it, I will simulate a data based on my distributions on SPSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. Those distributions are used only to *approximate* the distribution of your data. First of all, [normality checking is pretty useless procedure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/35989). Use the distribution [that is useful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/57407/35989) as an approximation of the distribution of your data, that shares the characteristics you find important. E.g. if the data is continuous and the distribution is roughly symmetric, Gaussian might be a reasonable choice, if you have roughly i.i.d. binary events, binomial might be a good choice, etc. Neither of those *is* the distribution of your data, they are just used to approximate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Let's put it that way. I need to select a distribution type for simulation. My variable is continuous Mean=  55, Stddev= 20. My range is from 0 to 120. Most frequency is at between 40-60,  I got 0 frequency between 80-100, but 2 frequencies at 20-40, 60-80 and 100-120. Distribution does not seem normal. But I cant identify how does it look...